# When to use "живот" or "желудок" – words for "stomach"

Tags: словоупотребление

In French, "*ventre*" and "*estomac*" can both translate as "*stomach*", albeit with certain nuances:

- "*ventre*": a more general, all-encompassing term referring to your (exterior) abdomen which contains your stomach, bowels etc, and a rather casual word.
- "*estomac*": a part-specific term referring to your stomach as an organ, and a bit on the formal side, often heard on a medical context.

I assume that in this respect, "живот" corresponds to "*ventre*" and "желудок" corresponds to "*estomac*".

---

But here's the contradiction I've realised. When I say the following  in conversation in a casual, non-medical context, I use "желудок":

> 1) На полный **желудок** и думается яснее.

... whereas in French only "*ventre*" fits this context:

> 1) Il n’y a rien de tel que d’avoir le **ventre** plein pour se tranquilliser l’esprit.

"*Avoir le ventre plein*" is something you'd say after having a hearty meal, while "*avoir l'estomac plein*" is more like what you'll see in a health-related or medical article. So, at least theoretically, I should be using "живот" here instead.

---

On a similar note, another contradictory case I notice:

> 2) И у меня **живот** вот-вот заурчит.

I use "живот" here, while  in French "*estomac*" more fits this context:

> 2) Mon **estomac** ne va pas tarder à crier famine non plus.

... although at least if its French equivalent is anything to go by, I should be using "желудок" in this case.

---

So on the surface, "живот" corresponds to "ventre" and "желудок" corresponds to "estomac". But in practice, when it comes to using them in a sentence, as part of an expression, I notice it can work the other way around. So the distinction between  "живот" and  "желудок" in Russian doesn't seem as clear-cut as I'd expected it to be.

Comment: (an aside) **На полный желудок и думается яснее** is an interesting statement, i've always known that the opposite was true

Comment: "Живот" also means "life" in old russian. And it still can be used in this meaning in idiomatic forms: "Сражаться живота не жалея" - "to fight wtihout care for own life" (not to not taking care of stomac)

Answer (score 2):

They are "clear-cut".

***Живот:***
[image: Живот]
***Желудок:***
[image: Желудок]

As for their usage in idiomatic (or semi-idiomatic) constructions, it's rarely any clear logic behind.
So as **shabunc♦**'s answer suggests: you just "remember it".

<sub>(Although speaking of similar French idioms I guess many will actually wonder why it's "ventre" which is "full". Many idioms sound strange from another language perspective.)</sub>

Comment: from the question I got the idea that the author actually knows what `живот` and `желудок` are standing for )

Comment: @shabunc♦ Sort of. But then he would not have a question like *the distinction between "живот" and "желудок" in Russian doesn't seem as clear-cut as I'd expected it to be*.

Answer (score 1):

One can just remember that:

1. `болит живот` and `в животе урчит`, `живот сводит [от голода, судорогой etc.]`, are idiomatic and interchangeable with (less used) `болит желудок`, `урчит в желудке`, `желудок сводит`.
2. `на полный желудок` is an idiom and way more frequently used than `на полный живот`.

That's pretty much it.

Comment: Can you think of some other examples where one is used significantly more often (or almost exclusively) than the other?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens I can not think of any off the of head to be honest -  there are plenty idiom with `живот` but in them `живот` never is interchangeable with `желудок` - like `хвататься за живот`, `не щадя живота своего` etc.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Btw. if you say "полный" about "живот" in Russian many would actually think of a "fat" one. Thus the "French logic"  will lead to "полный живот может быть пустым и наоборот".

Comment: I disagree with your first statement. When describing pain, I’d use живот for areas around navel and lower, and желудок for area around solar plexus.

Comment: @Neith you can google both phrases to see which one is actually more frequently used )

Comment: @shabunc How does it matter which one is more frequently used? Stomach pain due to gastritis and belly pain due to diarrhea feel quite different.

Comment: @Neith ah now I see your point, sorry for getting you wrong! I believe that it’s a reasonable statement (though personally me never did such distinction) and worth to exist in a form of separate answer )

Comment: @shabunc I’ve made an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When describing pain, I’d use `живот` for areas around navel  and lower where the intestines are, for example, during diarrhea. And I’d use `желудок` for area around solar plexus, for example, due to gastritis.